# DEC64 implementation in WebAssembly (Wasm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, decimal, webassembly

is it viable to have a DEC64[1] implementation in WebAssembly (Wasm)?

disclaimer: I'm not a system developer, but I'm willing to try to implement it if there is no fundamental impediment.

problem: I'm working with financial software and trying to use node.js on a few critical calculation. the problem is the historical deficient support for decimal numbers in JavaScript. on my domain precision of 16 digits is a must.

[1] http://www.dec64.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's feasible. Also, you have many options.

- You can write a native node addon using N-API
- WebAssembly with Node.js

In my opinion, you should go for writing a native node module, the reason being WASM isn't kinda stable in the Node environment.

If you already have the code written, then you can just compile it as WASM and use it.

If you are writing from scratch, then you create a library of functions, use them in the N-API module code, so that if you want to create a WASM module in the future, you can imply leverage that library.

Comment: thank you. I didn't know Wasm wasn't mature in node.js. But even though this is part of the problem, my question was regarding if Wasm is able to accommodate the low levels DEC64 implementation. The X64 code is in ASM (https://github.com/douglascrockford/DEC64). Not sure how to convert that in Wasm.